# babel-node fails when babel cli works correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-node

**EDIT:** The solution was to remove type=module from `package.json`

I'm trying to use `babel-node` and it's failing to pickup presets from `.babelrc`. The odd thing is the `babel` cli is working just fine.

This works:

```sh
$ npx babel src/build-html.js
```

This fails:

```sh
$ npx babel-node src/build-html.js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

This also works:

```sh
$ npx babel src/build-html.js | node
```

**.babelrc.yml**

```js
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build:html": "babel-node src/build-html.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1"
  }
}
```

**src/build-html.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

const HelloWorld = () => <div>Hello World</div>

const output = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<HelloWorld />)

console.log(output)
```

I put a repo up to help debug at `https://github.com/joelnet/mojo-gallery`

checkout the `stack-overflow` tag for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming .babelrc.yml => `mv .babelrc.yml babel.config.json` and then run `npx babel-node src/build-html.js` again

Comment: I'm still getting the same errors. I put a repo up to help debug at `https://github.com/joelnet/mojo-gallery`. checkout the `stack-overflow` tag for this issue.

Comment: The solution was to remove type=module from `package.json`